# ASP.NET MVC 2 RC: How to use the EditorFor to render correct name attributes for a List<>?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, collections, editorfor

In the [MVC RC 2 docs](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=7aba081a-19b9-44c4-a247-3882c8f749e3&displaylang=en), we find:

> Expression-based helpers that render input elements generate correct name attributes when the expression contains an array or collection index. For example, the value of the name attribute rendered by Html.EditorFor(m => m.Orders[i]) for the first order in a list would be Orders[0].

**Anyone care to link an example of the C# view code (using a List where the result can bind back to the Model upon post)?**

Just as a reference, I use the following code to verify the model binds correctly round trip.  It simply shows view that allows change, then displays a view with the edited data upon form submission.

```
[HandleError]
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var myStudents = new List<Student>();

        myStudents.Add(new Student { Name = "Harry" });
        myStudents.Add(new Student { Name = "Tom" });
        myStudents.Add(new Student { Name = "Richard" });
        var myClass = new Classroom {Students = myStudents};

        return View(myClass); // EditorFor()
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index( Classroom myClass)  
    {
        return View("IndexPost", myClass); // DisplayFor()
    }
```

Comment: The EditorFor now supports arrays and collections so that the index is part of the id for the input html tag.  What C# code could show how to use it, especially if you are using a List<> and you expect the data to model bind back to the original object?

Comment: The example shows a Classroom object with a List of Students.  I created a Classroom Template and a Student Template, but would like to know what C# code to put in the Classroom Template to render the students with an EditorFor so that when I post, it model binds back to the myClass object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code:

```
<% for (int count = 0; count < Model.Students.Count; count++ )
   {                                              %><%= 
      Html.EditorFor(m => m.Students[count])      %><%
   } 
%>
```

Rendered this output:

```
<input class="text-box single-line" id="Students_0__Name" name="Students[0].Name" type="text" value="Harry" />
<input class="text-box single-line" id="Students_1__Name" name="Students[1].Name" type="text" value="Tom" />
<input class="text-box single-line" id="Students_2__Name" name="Students[2].Name" type="text" value="Richard" />
```

And when I posted the content, the display was this (because I have a Student.ascx):

```
<table>
    <tr><td><span>Harry</span> </td></tr>
    <tr><td><span>Tom</span> </td></tr>
    <tr><td><span>Richard</span> </td></tr>
</table>
```

But that's it (I think).  Next question is how to get rid of those name="" tags.